# WicketRuntimeException: component logout not found on page LogIn

Tags: java, wicket

Login submit button:

```
if(loginAllowed) 
{
  if (!continueToOriginalDestination())
  {
    setResponsePage(General.class);
  }
}
```

General page logout button:

```
getWicketWebSession().invalidateNow();
getRequestCycle().setRedirect(true);
setResponsePage(LogIn.class);
```

It works good when user is in session. But when session expires and user click "logout" - we save in PageMap "general?wicket:interface=:1:logout::ILinkListener::" and when user log in - we get exception:

```
wicket.RequestCycle | org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: 
component logout not  found on page LogIn[id = 1], 
listener interface = [RequestListenerInterface name=ILinkListener, 
method=public abstract void
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ILinkListener.onLinkClicked()
```

But I'm still needed to redirect users and can't delete continueToOriginalDestination().
Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

**[removed original answer]**

I'm unable to reproduce your issue with a minimal test app using Wicket 6. Perhaps you are using a different version?

Either way, what you need to do is create a new LogoutPage which simply logs out the user and redirects him in the constructor. Then, change your logout button to a `BookmarkablePageLink` to that page. That link can't expire since it's bookmarkable.

Using a logout page instead of logging out in the link handler is better practice IMO because:

1. It will always work (no expired page).
2. Going the route of `RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException` when you want to logout seems counter-intuitive.
3. Your logout code is in a single place; you just need to link to the logout page to use it.
4. Adding the logout link like you have to a stateless page will make it stateful. Using the logout page avoids that.

Comment: Thanks, but in step 1 - I don't have logout button in LogIn.class. Here only two textfields (login and password, I check it in "loginAllowed") and submit button, which redirect to General.class or any other in "original destination". And only in General.class I have logout button. So it is strange for me, why wicket search this logout component on LogIn.class

Comment: In that case, I don't understand your sequence of actions and events properly. Please describe them more explicitly.

Comment: 1. User enters login/password in LogIn page and click "Submit"
2. In onSubmit() method in LogIn.class I check it and if success use continueToOriginalDestination() or setResponsePage(General.class);
3. Session time is 30 min (Tomcat preference). While user is in General page (for example) session expired, BUT user still on page.
4. User presses "Logout" link, BUT onClick() method for this link doesn't executes, and user straightly go to "/general?wicket:interface=:1:logout::ILinkListener::"

Comment: 5. Generall.class checks authentication  - and user hasn't authenticated session - so General use "throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(LogIn.class);" to redirect to LogIn page. Wicket also save "/general?wicket:interface=:1:logout::ILinkListener::" as "original destination" link for method continueToOriginalDestination() as I understand.
6. User enters login/password again - and if succes - I have exception that "logout" component not found on page LogIn.
Sorry if I'm not clear and thank you very much.

Comment: Quick comment: you should edit the original question to add this information instead.